# Безопасное, но не безопасное приведение int в float

Tags: c#

Приведение `int` к `float` проходит неявно, а раз неявно значит безопасно, но так говорится в книгах и различных видео.

Заминка у меня случилась когда выполнил это:

```
float a = int.MaxValue; // 2_147_483_647
Console.WriteLine(a);   // Вывод: 2,1474836E+09
```

Решил в цикле перебрать и оказалось что со значения 16777217 приведение не безопасно.

```
int a = 16777217;
float b = a;
Console.WriteLine(b); // Вывод 16777216
```

Понимаю например почему byte в short, int, long совершено безопасно проходит:

```
byte a = 255;   //                                                                                       1111 1111
short b = a;    //                                                                           0000 0000   1111 1111
int c = a;      //                                                  0000 0000    0000 0000   0000 0000   1111 1111
long d = a;     // 0000 0000    0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000    0000 0000   0000 0000   1111 1111
```

Почему `int` во `float` не требует явного приведения ?

Comment: Вообще эта потеря точности [задокументирована](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions), так что наверное можно считать, что про "неявно значит безопасно" вас обманули

Comment: @andreymal оО блин, не договорили получается xD

Comment: "до точки и после неё" - этот вопрос бессмысленен, потому что float и double - это числа с **плавающей** точкой

Comment: @andreymal, ааа, ок, понял. Не даром они так называются, сглупил.

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понимаю, что такое "безопасное приведение" вообще. Это без потери точности имеется в виду?

Comment: @CrazyElf например цитата из книги Прайса: "Неявное происходит автоматически, и это безопасно, то есть вы 
не потеряете никакую информацию."

Comment: @andreymal о да, там тоже), да много кто так говорит и пишет(. А я верил, пока не проверил(

Comment: Если посмотреть на [Число с плавающей запятой в вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9), то видно, что у **float** мантисса (значимые биты) **24 бита**, а у  **double 52**

Comment: @avp оО спасибо вам, теперь я понимаю почему точность возможна только до диапазона `16777215` у `float`.

Comment: @Vipz, как говорил еще Козьма Прутков -- зри в корень